# Etymology of 'ends' or 'the ends' and other current British/London slang

Tags: etymology, slang

I'd like to know more about how 'ends' came to mean 'hometown' in current London slang. I have heard it used to mean money, which is an extension of mainstream use - means to an end, for one's own ends etc. Can anyone enlighten me?

Also, is there are decent source of general etymological information on current slang words? I know a lot come from Caribbean words and American hip-hop but a central source would be great.

Comment: Do you have some example use? A sentence you've heard or read?

Comment: I would hazard a guess that it's related to football, related to  home end and away end.

Comment: It could do, but London has had a West End and an East End for a very long time.

Answer (score 6):

The London slang *ends* probably came from Jamaican slang, where it seems to have been more generic or local.

[The London Slang Dictionary Project](http://www.timwoods.org/the-london-slang-dictionary-project/) ("written by teenagers for their peers and
for their teachers") includes:

> **Ends** - Area, neighbourhood
>
> **From ends** — one who is “from the streets” and so knows what’s going on.

The second highest definition in Urban Dictionary is the London one:

> your 'ends' is your area
>
> *"what ends you from?"*
>
> by §håÐðw May 21, 2004

A similar meaning can be found in this [Jamaican Slang Glossary](http://www.speakjamaican.com/glossary/):

> Ends- A place. Mi a go pon one ends still.
>   (I am going to one place).

And in [Backayard Magazine's patois guide](http://www.backayard.com/patois/patois_index.html):

> **ends,** colloq. home, familiar place.

Another [Urban Dictionary](http://ends.urbanup.com/1990037) definition includes both London and Jamaican meanings:

> Jamaican word for street corner
>   London word for dodgy area
>
> *Mi pon di ends (Quote from Dwayne of the Verne)*
>
> *Rah, SE22? You on the ends bruv (quote from Andrew of SE5)*
>
> *West Norwood? Wha yah wanna move there to, thats verging on the ends man (quoute from Philly of SW16)*
>
> Related words: hood ghetto yard briccie peckz
>
> by bombskwad - detonating warfare wiv lyrics Sep 22, 2006

The [W?Dictionary of
Jamaican Dialect i.e. Patois](http://www.whaddat.com/dictionary/) says:

> **Ends**: (n.) Hang out spot/area, place to chill,
>   (v.) **ends out**: the act of hanging out

Finally, [Talk Jamaican](http://talkjamaican.blogspot.com/2007/04/jamaican-patois-e.html?m=1) says:

> **ends** : destination, home (pon de ends = at home)

Some of these Jamaican definitions say *ends* is a destination, so the place at the end of a journey.

Answer (score 0):

I’ve not heard it, but [‘Chambers Slang Dictionary’](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Chambers-Slang-Dictionary-Jonathon-Green/dp/0550104399/ref=sr_ob_2?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1340282639&sr=1-2) (recommended) gives singular *end*, in the sense of ‘an area of a city’ as a UK black/teen term, dating from the 1990s. I suppose it may have come from references to the end of a town (‘Which end of town are you from?’), or it may be associated in some way with the area behind the goals of  a football pitch reserved for supporters of the home and away teams.